How do I start multiple projects one after the other in Spring Boot Dashboard in STS?
I have 16 projects I need to run in Spring Boot Dashboard at the same time. It's annoying and time consuming to start them manually every time, plus since they're running at the same time, the latter projects lag when I start them up.
Is there a way to configure the projects so that I can start them one after the other? I should mention that I need to launch a given profile and also start them in a specific order (3 of them need to be started in a specific order and then the other 16 can be launched in any order).
Is this possible, and how?

There are different ways to launch multiple projects. I am not sure which one fits your needs best, but here is what I am aware of:

you can tag applications (or launch configs) in the boot dashboard and then trim down the list of displayed applications by using the tag to filter the list of displayed apps. That way, you could easily create different tags for those different group of apps that you have, filter down to a tag, select all, and press "run". It is still not fully automated, but maybe helps in your situation.

the other option that comes to my mind is a launch group in the regular Eclipse launch config dialog. It allows you to group different launch configs to a group and set various options for each launch (like setting a delay, waiting for a specific output on the console, etc.). I haven't used this myself yet, so can't provide a lot of details, but maybe worth checking out.



If I could create four tags for the four things that I have to launch in order - one of each application then 13 applications as a group - that'll solve my problem, somewhat.
